# regular expression split : FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, split

I am getting a warning in Python 3 version when I use `split()` command as follows:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\s*')
match = re.split(pattern, 'I am going to school')
print(match)
```

> python3.6/re.py:212: FutureWarning: split()
>   requires a non-empty pattern match.   return _compile(pattern,
>   flags).split(string, maxsplit)

I don't understand why I am getting this warning.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are getting this warning because with the `\s*` pattern you asked to split on substrings of *zero or more* whitespaces

But... the empty string matches that pattern, because there are zero whitespaces in it!

It's unclear what `re.split` should do with this. This is what `str.split` does:

```
>>> 'hello world'.split('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: empty separator
>>>
```

`re.split` decides to just throw away that empty substring option, and instead splits on *one or more* whitespaces. In python3.6 it emits that `FutureWarning` you're seeing, to tell you about that decision.

You could say that yourself by replacing `*` with `+`:

```
$ python3.6 -c "import re; print(re.split('\s*', 'I am going to school'))"
/usr/lib64/python3.6/re.py:212: FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
  return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
['I', 'am', 'going', 'to', 'school']

$ python3.6 -c "import re; print(re.split('\s+', 'I am going to school'))"
['I', 'am', 'going', 'to', 'school']
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example, i found that, you are trying to split string with multiple char using separator "|", but you did not add proper syntax
Ex:
Before : [|\s**|**
After(right syntax) : [|\s

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).