# Split() giving a futures warning

Tags: python, regex

What would be the correct way to remedy the following warning, and why is the warning occurring in the first place?

```
>>> import re
>>> _split_path = re.compile(r'\.|(?=\[)').split
>>> _split_path('Genre')
<string>:1: FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
['Genre']
```

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564710/regular-expression-split-futurewarning-split-requires-a-non-empty-pattern-m?rq=1

Comment: @Xteven but I don't have a `\s` in there? What should the regex be instead? Or, should I be calling it differently?